# OpenTTD Jukebox?

Tags: openttd

I'm enjoying OpenTTD a lot more than Transport Tycoon Deluxe, but I miss the jazz jukebox from that game; there's a poor variety of music in OpenTTD. Does this feature exist in OpenTTD? If so, where can it be found?

Comment: Related: http://www.tt-forums.net/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=46479

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, about the Jazz jukebox specifically, it does exist in OpenTTD:

[image: Jazz Jukebox]

I'm not sure how closely it matches the original, having never actually played the original. If you want the original game's music in OpenTTD, see the OpenTTD Wiki's [installation instruction](http://wiki.openttd.org/FAQ_installation#What_files_do_I_need_from_TTD.3F):

> If you also want music, *(the all important cheesy midi goodness)* copy the following files to the `gm/` folder:
>
> - Music files: **`*.gm`**